# Can I make a single template<typename T> apply to multiple definitions/declarations?

Tags: c++, templates, idioms, syntactic-sugar

In C++, I'd like to be able to say:

```
template <typename T> {
void foo(T t1);
void bar(T t1, T t2);
}
```

i.e. have the `template <typename T>` apply to multiple definitions/declarations. The `{ }` syntax in the above doesn't compile; is there another way to express the same?

**Note:** Wrapping the functions in a struct/class won't do, I want something that's both terse and without any dummy entities.

Comment: Nope there isn`t such unicorn.

Comment: If you can wait for it, you could use `auto` parameter types from C++17 concepts.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Well, seeing how I'm living without this now I guess I can wait :-) but how will C++17 `auto` changes address this? If you make it into an answer I can upvote it...

Comment: I'll give you a little write-up if you like, gotta procrastinate somehow!

Comment: @CoffeeandCode: Please do :-)

Comment: If there is a lot of function like this, you can concider wrapping them into a templated class and declare them static, so you should define the template parameter only once. It's not a good design choice if these are unrelated functions tho.

Comment: @Melkon: I specifically said I wanted to avoid this - because I'm doing just that on occasion and I really don't like it (sigh).

Comment: Ahh, i am blind, sorry

Answer (score 4):

If you can wait for [C++17 concepts](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4361.pdf), you could use `auto` parameter types instead of using templates.

Say I have the following C++17 function:

```
auto func(auto x, auto y){
    return x + y;
}
```

This could be re-written in C++14 like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto func(T x, U y){
    return x + y;
}
```

Which could be re-written again in C++11 like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
auto func(T x, U y) -> typename std::decay<decltype(x + y)>::type{
    return x + y;
}
```

as @T.C. stated in the comments, the [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) is necessary here because the semantics of auto return type in c++14 will decay the final statement whereas `decltype(x + y)` will not decay the expressions type. If we wanted to not decay the return expressions type we would write:

```
// template here for c++14
decltype(auto) func(auto x, auto y){
    return x + y;
}
```

So, given this information we could re-write your functions like this:

```
void foo(auto t1);
void bar(auto t1, auto t2);
```

Remembering that if we ever need to reference the types of the arguments we will need to use `decltype`.

---

If you intend on using the types extensively templates are a much better idea, but to keep the brevity of the function declaration in the function definition we could write some `using` statements for the types:

```
void bar(auto t1, auto t2){
    using type_t1 = std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>;
    using type_t2 = std::decay_t<decltype(t2)>;
}
```

The need for `std::decay_t` in this situation arises if we pass in a pointer or reference with some cv qualifier. We only want the underlying type.

Then to enforce that the underlying types of `type_t1` and `type_t2` are the same as in your example we could use `SFINAE` to exclude any instantiation of `bar` where they are not:

```
auto bar(auto t1, auto t2) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>, std::decay_t<decltype(t2)>>::value>{
    using type = std::decay_t<decltype(t1)>;
}
```

again, decaying the type so that if we get pointers we are comparing the underlying type.

Just remember to ask yourself if this is all worth it just to not have to write `template<typename T>` a few more times.

Comment: (Not the downvoter) Your C++14 and C++11 versions are not the same. Also, that final sfinae is rather ridiculous.

Comment: @T.C. how so? I'll correct it if you let me know how

Comment: Your C++11 version, modulo SFINAE, is equivalent to returning `decltype(auto)` in C++14. Returning `auto` decays the type.

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I'll fix that up